Perl DBI with Mariadb Maxscale
I have set up a Mariadb Maxscale (1 Primary and 2 Replicas) replication cluster for experimentation purposes. As I understand it the main purpose for using Maxscale is that it decides what server to query. Accordingly, I am unsure how to direct my DBI query to Maxscale instead of a specific server.
I usually use Perl DBI to connect to databases in the following manner;
my $dbh = DBI->connect("DBI:mysql:database=$db_name};$server",$user,$passwd);
Can someone tell me how to do this with Maxscale?
maxctrl list servers
┌─────────┬─────────────┬──────┬─────────────┬─────────────────┬──────────┬─────────────────┐
│ Server  │ Address     │ Port │ Connections │ State           │ GTID     │ Monitor         │
├─────────┼─────────────┼──────┼─────────────┼─────────────────┼──────────┼─────────────────┤
│ server1 │ 192.168.0.2 │ 3306 │ 0           │ Master, Running │ 0-2-1438 │ MariaDB-Monitor │
├─────────┼─────────────┼──────┼─────────────┼─────────────────┼──────────┼─────────────────┤
│ server2 │ 192.168.0.3 │ 3306 │ 0           │ Slave, Running  │ 0-2-1438 │ MariaDB-Monitor │
├─────────┼─────────────┼──────┼─────────────┼─────────────────┼──────────┼─────────────────┤
│ server3 │ 192.168.0.4 │ 3306 │ 0           │ Slave, Running  │ 0-2-1438 │ MariaDB-Monitor │
└─────────┴─────────────┴──────┴─────────────┴─────────────────┴──────────┴─────────────────┘

I seem to be able to connect as I can do:
$ mysql -h 192.168.0.1 -umaxscale -ppasswd -P4006 -e 'SHOW DATABASES;'
+--------------------+
| Database           |
+--------------------+
| admin              |
| information_schema |
| mysql              |
| performance_schema |
| sys                |
| test               |
+--------------------+

I just can't figure out how to successfully query via Perl DBI.

MaxScale is just a proxy. You should be able to connect as you would usually when connecting to MariaDB:
my $dsn = "DBI:mysql:database=$database;host=$max_scale_host;port=$max_scale_port";
my $dbh = DBI->connect($dsn, $user, $password);

You just have to make sure your DBI is aiming at the MaxScale host and port.

Thanks for the reply but when I do: perl -e 'use DBI; my $dsn = "DBI:mysql:database=admin;host=192.168.0.1;port=4406"; my $dbh = DBI->connect($dsn, "maxscale", "password");'DBI connect('database=admin;host=192.168.0.1;port=4406','maxscale',...) failed: Can't connect to server on '192.168.0.1' (115) at -e line 1. maxscale is the user and 4006 is the port I set in /etc/maxscale.cnf. I also tried with port 3306 and with no port at all. I will edit the question to show output from maxctrl list servers.

I've played around with the syntax and now I get: failed: Access denied for user 'maxscale'@'192.168.0.1' to database 'admin'. Note, I do not have mariadb installed on the maxcale machine (192.168.0.1) is that a requirement?

That error means that the user maxscale does not have access to that database. You should use your normal database users when connecting through MaxScale, the user and password defined in the config are for MaxScale's internal use only. Another thing to look into is the proxy_protocol which makes using MaxScale a lot nicer.

mysql -h 192.168.0.1 -umaxscale -ppsswd -P4006 -e 'SHOW DATABASES;' works.

This: perl -e 'use DBI; my $dbh = DBI->connect("DBI:mysql:database=admin;host=192.168.0.1;port=4006", "maxscale", "password");' once I fixed some permission issues. Thanks Rawley for your help!
